# Call SOAP service from GAE/J

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, soap, jax-ws

I want make soap call from my GAE application. It does work properly at localhost, but at deploying it throws exception

```
 ....
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection <init>: Unable to make javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address accessible.
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-fe1b1a37f7387808(Request.java)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.<init>(Accessor.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.AccessorFactoryImpl.createFieldAccessor(AccessorFactoryImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createFieldSeed(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:252)
....
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,50]
Message: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:591)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamReaderFilter.next(XMLStreamReaderFilter.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:76)
```

Actually, the question is can I access SOAP services from GAE/J nowadays?  Whats difference from accessing it from local environment and GAE? And, of course, how I can fix my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was problem with soap server's permissions. GAE supports soap from version 1.4.2 [(link)](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html#cl).

Comment: How could a soap server permission cause a Reflection error on your GAE app? Were you using GAE as a SOAP client endpoint?

Comment: I'm also experiencing a problem with SOAP on GAE. Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643218/error-in-javax-xml-ws-service-initialization-on-app-engine