# Error in javax.xml.ws.Service initialization on App Engine

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP server from GAE. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003761/simple-curl-failing-from-linux-command-line/11321675#11321675).
It all works fine on the development server but on production I get a 500 error during initialization. After a lot of digging, I managed to catch a Throwable and log a stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:58)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:142)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:102)
```

This problem may be related to [Issue 4910](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4910). One suggestion there says:

> What I meant above is that you should not put any jar files
>   implementing jaxws itself into your war. The App Engine runtime
>   contains an implementation of jaxws and you should use that one.

In my classpath I've found

1. xml-apis-1.0.b2,=.jar
2. jaxb-api.jar
3. jaxb-impl.jar

They don't look like jaxws implementations, well at least as far as I understand. Can't really do without jaxb (I get an error if I remove that jar).

Any suggestion is welcome.

[update]
[It seems][3](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4910#c41) that just having jaxb in the classpath causes a problem so that GAE's jaxws implementation cannot be found.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692865/how-does-java-initialize-the-jaxb-jax-ws-etc-implementation) is also useful to understand how jaxws initialzation works.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I've given up on GAE's implementation of jaxws.
Their implementation can't be found by the Factory classloader, period.

So I've picked the [Force.com Web Services Connecto](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/)r and managed to make it work.
There were bugs in the code generation process, in the generated code, and also the GAE connector needed some fixes.

I'm tempted to created a project on GitHub to show what I've done.
This implementation is faster and also you can set the socket timeout!